# PyQt4 - Delete QWidgets and create new

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

"I want to delete and reinstantiate a QWidget." I am writing a GUI in PyQt4 and for that I write classes which inherit from `QGridLayout`. These would look like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class StartTab(QtGui.QGridLayout):

    def __init__(self, mainWindow, tab):

        super(StartTab, self).__init__(tab)

        < body (whatever this tab needs) >
```

Here `mainWindow` is somewhat the framing window of the GUI to which the menu bar belongs and is instatiated when the program starts. So things like "File -> New Project" will be handled in this class. When the program starts, the tabs will be created in the `__init__` of `mainWindow`, so like:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from start_tab import StartTab
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        < some variables >

        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)

        self.tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.startTab = StartTab(self, self.tab1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, 'Start Tab')

        < some other tabs >
```

In `mainWindow` I also have a function `newProject()` which is called when the user hits the above mentioned "File -> New Project" button. There is my problem. I tried reinitializing the tabs in the `newProject()` function so the old tabs will be deleted and new ones will be created when the user wants to start a new project from a running program. I don't know how though. What I tried is somewhat to just copy the line from the `__init__` of `mainWindow`:

```
def newProject(self) :
    self.startTab = StartTab(self, self.tab1)
```

but this leaves me with an error message:

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "", which already has
>   a layout

I know I probably haven't understood the concept of this whole Qt thing yet, but I would much appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you inheriting from a layout? Are you implementing a new layout?

Comment: The task appears to be more suitable for QStackedWidget.

Comment: Actually @KubaOber I can't tell you because I took over on this project from somebody else who isn't available anymore and this person did this.

Comment: Understood. The error you see means exactly what it says: for some reason, you're attempting to set a layout on a widget hat has a layout already.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I don't know who to solve the actual problem I described namely creating a new set of QWidgets for my GUI and deleting the old ones.

Comment: Maybe you have a suggestion for a better title to this problem.